# AttributeError: "platforms" object has no attribute "image"

Tags: python

I am a self taught programmer and I have recently been building this platformer game. I have been stuck for quite  while now and cant seem to fix any more errors. I do have multiple files so the error could lie elsewhere in my code and there may be more than one. Ive looked at it for hours and nothing has come to mind. I would be grateful if anyone could help me fix this code.

[here is the link](https://pastebin.com/06VJuAJh) to the code

here is the file for the code that currently has an error:

```
   class Levels():

   world_snap = 0

    #This is a list of sprites used within the game 
    platform_array = None

    #This is the variable for the background image
    level_background = None

    #This controls the movement of the screen with the level
    world_scroll = 0
    level_handleing = -1000

    def __init__ (self, player):

        #This code is used when a player collides with a platform 
        self.platform_array = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player


    def update_level(self):
        #This code updates the level throughout 
        self.platform_array.update()


    def output(self, screen):
        color = (255, 0, 0)

        #This code draws the background
        screen.fill(color)
        screen.blit(self.background, (self.world_scroll // 3,0))

        #This code draws the sprite lists
        self.platform_array.draw(screen)


    def snap_world(self, snap_x):

        #This code takes into account the amount of shift in the world 
        self.world_snap += snap_x

        #This shifts all of the sprite lists
        for platform in self.platform_array:
            platform.rect.x += snap_x


#Creating the first level
class level_1(Levels):

    def __init__(self, player):

        #This code calls the parent constructor so the attribute player is known
        Levels.__init__(self, player)

        background_color = (255, 255, 255)

        self.background = pygame.image.load("better_background.jpg").convert()
        self.background.set_colorkey(background_color)
        self.level_limit = -2500

        #This code puts the x and y values of the platform into the array
        level = [ [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_on_left, 500, 500],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_in_middle, 570, 500],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_on_right, 640, 500],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_on_left, 800, 400],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_in_middle, 870, 400],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_on_right, 940, 400],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_on_left, 1000, 500],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_in_middle, 1070, 500],
                  [Final_Project_Platforms.grass_on_right, 1140, 500],
                  ]

        #This code goes through the array and adds the platforms
        for platforms in level:
            tile = Final_Project_Platforms.platforms(platforms[0])
            tile.rect.x = platforms[1]
            tile.rect.y = platforms[2]
            tile.player = self.player
            self.platform_array.add(tile)
```

The error is:

```
line 38, in output self.platform_array.draw(screen) 
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw 
self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect) AttributeError: 
'platforms' object has no attribute 'image'`
```

Im looking forward to seeing the replies

thank you.

Comment: You have to tell us what the error is.

Comment: the error is in the title

Comment: sorry i am new here so i dont really know how to ask the question.

Comment: this is the actual error

Comment: line 38, in output
    self.platform_array.draw(screen)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
AttributeError: 'platforms' object has no attribute 'image'

Comment: Please post the full traceback in your question. People tend not to read comments and you can't format properly in comments.

Comment: ive done that now. hopefully it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which line the error is showing up, but try to uncomment the following line:

`self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])`

Comment: this made the game run however it looks nothing like i expected and the sprite images that i wanted as platforms have turned to normal blocks.